# Размер памяти приложения под Android

Tags: android

Как посмотреть размер памяти, занимаемой приложением под Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или зайти в Settings/Applications/Running Services, или выполнить procrank в отладочной консоли.

```
$ adb shell
# procrank
```